# Changing time value in timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I'm trying to update a timestamp's Time (hour and minutes) with new values, but for some reasons it returns with -19 hours, why is that? Am I doing it the wrong way?

```
$hour_created = $_REQUEST['hour_created'];     // ex.: 13
$minute_created = $_REQUEST['minute_created']; // ex.: 00

$updated_timestamp = strtotime("$hour_created:$minute_created", $_REQUEST['_timestamp']);
```

Comment: What is your server's current time? and please check if it is related with time zone. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a colleague, I ended up doing this:

```
$day_value = 60 * 60 * 24;
$offset    = intval($_REQUEST['_offset']) * 60;

// Article creation date
$time_created = ($_REQUEST['hour_created'] * 60 * 60) + ($_REQUEST['minute_created'] * 60);
$date_created = substr($_REQUEST['_timestamp'], 0, -3) - $offset;
$date_created = floor($date_created / $day_value) * $day_value + $time_created + $offset;
```

Offset is the result of the javascript function: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`
Timestamp is the result of `$.datepicker({altFormat: '@'});`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$updated_timestamp = strtotime(date("d/m/y", $_REQUEST['_timestamp'])." $hour_created:$minute_created");
```

And if this doesn't work, your server may require reverse date order (United States):

```
$updated_timestamp = strtotime(date("m/d/y", $_REQUEST['_timestamp'])." $hour_created:$minute_created");
```

If you want to replace hours and minutes and leave the date.

**EDIT:** Sorry, my mistake, fixed now.